# Match text between first and last word

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression that matches across multiple lines. This regular expression should start by matching a line beginning with `Email` and end by matching a line beginning with `=`, and it should include all lines in the match. Example:

**Input:**

```
scrambled text asdasdad
qwert asd

Email: johndoe@john.com
John is an emplyer
john's number is +146546****
============================

gabrish
```

**Match:**

```
Email: johndoe@john.com
John is an emplyer
john's number is +146546****
============================
```

Comment: In your example, what is the "first word" and the "last word"?

Comment: What *defines* a word in your example? Also, what have you tried? What makes `gabrish` a word and `number` not a word?

Comment: _"between first and last word"_ What you've described and what you've shown are two different things. Please clarify.

Comment: Also what language/tool are you working with?

Comment: **Scrambled** is the first word. Why do you not want to match **text asdasdad...**

Comment: `Javascript`, `C#`, `php`, `python`. Surely you must know more programming languages than just those, or...? To name a few more, how about `Go`, `C++`, `Fortran`, `WhiteSpace`?

Comment: @RufusL First word Email and Last word =

Comment: You ask how to get the text between the first word (scrambled) and the last word (gabrish). But then what you show you want to get as result is not exactly the text between the first word (scrambled) and the last word (gabrish). I really don't know what your really want. It would help if you would ask in a non-confusing, concise way...

Comment: @elgonzo i tagged those languages because the problem goes with all of  them.

Comment: I do not believe that you want to implement the code/regex in _all_ of the languages you tagged there...

Comment: @AlanWake To clarify: what you want is to find all lines between where the first line begins with "Email" and where the last line begins with "=". You specifically want a regular expression that accomplishes this goal. Correct?

Comment: @B.Fleming Yes that's what i'm talking about. Do you know any solution?

Comment: `\Email:.*=\s`
s is for singleline, which includes linebreakes in the match.
regex is greedy, so it includes all the ===. you can add a {,x} behind the = to specify the exact cout you want to match. have fun!

Comment: I've edited your question to better clarify what kind of solution you're looking for. Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: @Chris not works bro

Comment: @AlanWake https://regex101.com/r/fyQAVW/1

Comment: @Chris yeah thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to design an expression for this task, my guess is that, maybe this expression might be of our interest here,

```
Email:[\s\S]*?=.+\s*
```

with an `m` (multiline) flag:

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/r2t9Vi/1/)

if likely spaces after the last `=` might be unnecessary, we can just remove those and simplify it to: `Email:[\s\S]*?=.+`.

---

Another way would be to use an `s` (single line) flag and we would be starting with an expression similar to:

```
Email.*?=+
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/8DK8hk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
content.replaceAll("^(?!(EMAIL|=).+).+$", "");
```